# how can i unpack a column of type list in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in pyspark, the df has a column of type array string, so I need to generate a new column with the head of the list and also I need other columns with the concat of the tail list.

This is my original dataframe:

```
pyspark> df.show()
+---+------------+
| id|     lst_col|
+---+------------+
|  1|[a, b, c, d]|
+---+------------+


pyspark> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- lst_col: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

And I need to generate something like this:

```
pyspark> df2.show()
+---+--------+---------------+
| id|lst_head|lst_concat_tail|
+---+--------+---------------+
|  1|       a|          b,c,d|
+---+--------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Spark 2.4+, you can use `element_at`, `slice` and `size` functions for arrays:

```
df.select("id",
          element_at("lst_col", 1).alias("lst_head"),
          expr("slice(lst_col, 2, size(lst_col))").alias("lst_concat_tail")
         ).show()
```

Gives:

```
+---+--------+---------------+
| id|lst_head|lst_concat_tail|
+---+--------+---------------+
|  1|       a|      [b, c, d]|
+---+--------+---------------+
```